# Qlikview reports / chart not generating or printing in colour

Tags: business-intelligence, qlikview, qliksense

I have a qlik view report with a colour chart in it which isnt printing in colour, printer is set to colour and also the print preview is in B&W

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered this after some playing around.

```
At chart level
```

In your sheet Right click the chart you want to print in colour and click properties.

Then choose the Colours tab and untick "When Printing" in the Use patterns Instead of Colours section (top right)

```
For document level
```

Settings > User Preferences > Printing Tab

In chart colours you can force colour there.